# Mypy behavior when the object passes through a typeshed function?

Tags: python-3.x, mypy

I dont seem to understand Mypy's behaviour in the following case. The code is simplified for this question

```
import typing as t
...

self._store:t.Dict[str,str] = dict()
...

def set_kv(self, key:str, value:int)->t.Any:
    assert isinstance(key, six.string_types)
    assert isinstance(value, six.string_types)
    with self.__lock.write():
        self.__store[key] = value
        self.__persist()
```

I test this code with mypy by running the following command

```
mypy docido_sdk/index/test.py --ignore-missing-imports --follow-imports=error --strict-optional
```

now ideally this should throw an error at line `self.__store[key]= value`. But it does not. 
When I remove `assert isinstance(value, six.string_types)`, only then does it throw an error. The isinstance is a typshed function given below

```
def isinstance(__o: object, __t: Union[type, Tuple[Union[type, Tuple], ...]]) -> bool: ...
```

Is this a bug or an expected behaviour of mypy, because if I understand correctly `isinstance` should not affect the understanding of mypy about the type of `value`.

Comment: thanks for the reply guyz, I thought mypy didnt know what six.string_types meant. Both answers are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `isinstance()` you are making a runtime assertion about the type of `value`.

Before the call to `isinstance()` mypy thinks `value` is an `int` but actually at runtime it could be something different. After the `isinstance()` call `value` must be a `str`.

mypy knows about `isinstance()`, so it takes it as an explicit instruction to override whatever it thought it knew about `value` and update its model accordingly.

Likewise if you had `value: Union[int, str]` then after a check `if isinstance(value, str): ...` mypy can update its view of the universe and know `value` is now a `str` rather than an `int`. That's a case where this would seem more intuitive.

The problem here is that the possible types don't intersect, so mypy just takes the type as the only thing it can be: `str`.

As an aside, typescript would handle this kind of situation rather better as it has a type `never` for cases like this that should never happen and will generate errors when you operate on `never` values unexpectedly.

Mypy doesn't have that concept so it isn't as good at catching this kind of problem because it could actually be deliberate: the type system is providing hints only so you might reasonably have code that makes runtime assertions to handle cases where the type assumptions are wrong.

Comment: Both answers are correct, I am only selecting this answer because it has more relevant details in it. I also probably might end up using some of the comments in my research ;D.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be expected behavior for mypy: mypy does use `isinstance` calls for type inference, and mypy does not raise type errors in unreachable code.

According to the [current documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#complex-type-tests), mypy uses `isinstance` checks to infer types of variables (though not expressions like `type(o) is ...`). It gives the following example:

```
def f(o: object) -> None:
    if isinstance(o, int):  # Mypy understands isinstance checks
        g(o + 1)        # Okay; type of o is inferred as int here
        ...
```

Which shows code that is only reachable if `o` is an `int`. Mypy realizes this and assumes `o` is an `int`. This is reasonable because it is impossible for the code to run if it's not true.

In your code, `self.__store[key] = value` is only reachable if `value` is a `str` (under Python 3, `six.string_types` is `(str,)`). The difference in your code is that it's impossible for the assert to be true. So the code simply never runs. So there is no way for that code to be run and cause a type error.

[Elsewhere in the documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/more_types.html#the-noreturn-type), they give an example of mypy not type checking unreachable code:

> ```
> from typing import NoReturn
>
> def stop() -> NoReturn:
>     raise Exception('no way')
> ```
>
> Mypy will ensure that functions annotated as returning `NoReturn` truly never return, either implicitly or explicitly. Mypy will also recognize that the code after calls to such functions is unreachable and will behave accordingly:
>
> ```
> def f(x: int) -> int:
>     if x == 0:
>         return x
>     stop()
>     return 'whatever works'  # No error in an unreachable block
> ```

Notice the phrasing they use: "will behave accordingly". This is what many people would expect a type checker to do with unreachable code.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I thought mypy didnt know what six.string_types meant